# "Current user *** have no permission.",it showed this while using SqlCacheDependency and HttpRuntime.Cache.How to solve it?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlcachedependency, httpruntime.cache

```
SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableNotifications(connString);
SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableTableForNotifications(connString, tableName);
SqlCacheDependency sqlDenpendency = new SqlCacheDependency(entryName, tableName);
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key,lstData,sqlDenpendency,DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

When I used SqlCacheDependency to save some data into `HttpRuntime.Cache` like this,there was a runtime error as following:

> Current user uu163 have no permission .
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Current user uu163 have no permission .
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2442126
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5736904
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +628
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +3731
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +940
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +272
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +280
>      System.Web.Caching.SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.SetupNotifications(Int32 flags, String table, String connectionString) +752

How to solve this error?

Comment: Add permissions to user `uu163` ?

Comment: You can try adding permissions to that user, but this is certainly a custom error message.  You might want to try looking for whatever throws that error to see why it's throwing it.

Comment: I've got the reason of this error that the user had no permission to create roles which SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableNotifications need.Thanks!